# Event listener removing issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Three Div elements with box appearance,
when user click at any div a copy from this div will be added to the
end (the fired div wont be clickable any more, and the new div will
be clickable). And so on…..

I have tried this but it creates two divs at the same time and the div can be clickable again .!!

```
<div id="parent" class="p">
    <div class="red" class="d"></div>
    <div class="green" class="d"></div>
    <div class="blue" class="d"></div>
</div>
```

```
#parent{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

.red{
   
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 2px;
}`your text`
.green{
    
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 2px;
}
.blue{
   
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```
let parent = document.querySelector("#parent");
let div = document.querySelectorAll(".p div");

parent.addEventListener("click", function createDiv(e){ 
console.log('1');
let child = document.createElement("div");
parent.append(child);
child.classList.add(e.target.className);
console.log(e);
e.target.removeEventListener("click",createDiv());
});
```

Comment: what is `your text` in your css ?

Comment: Making use of [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) frees the OP from dealing with the issues described by the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way...

An eventListener is a link between a DOM element and a function.

To remove any event listener you need to use the same pair [ DOM element / function ]

In your case this link is on the parent and not on any of his divs.
so you cantt remove any link between of his initial divs.

```js
const
  parent = document.querySelector('#parent')
, cDivs  = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div')
  ;
cDivs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', createDiv)) // don't recreate x time your function `createDiv`
  ;
function createDiv({currentTarget: initialDiv}) // just declare it only one time
  {
  initialDiv.removeEventListener('click', createDiv)
    ;
  parent
    .appendChild( initialDiv.cloneNode(true) )  // this one return the clone
    .addEventListener('click', createDiv)
  }
```

```css
#parent {
  display   : flex;
  flex-wrap : wrap;
  }
#parent > div {
  width  : 50px;
  height : 50px;
  margin : 2px;
  }
.red {
  background : red;
  }
.green {
  background : green;
  }
.blue {
  background : blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="p">
  <div class="red"   ></div>
  <div class="green" ></div>
  <div class="blue"  ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("parent");

// all clicks on the parent are handled by one function
parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // get the element that was clicked on
  const el = e.target;
  // check to be sure the click is on an inner div and if it was already clicked
  if (el !== this && !el.dataset.clicked) {
    // clone it
    const clone = el.cloneNode(true);
    // add it to the end
    this.appendChild(clone);
    // mark the one that was clicked on
    el.dataset.clicked = true;
  }
});
```

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#parent>div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="p">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you press between the colored divs it produce a column of cloned divs.

Comment: Ah - good catch - test if the target is not ‘this’